# What is the alternative of this pandas groupby in pyspark

Tags: pandas, pyspark

I am converting my code to pyspark. Please find the example below and what is the alternative to convert to pyspark ? I couldnt see shift in pyspark. The main purpose of the below code is it checks the next row and cumulatively sum the value when it is not equal.

```
example['date_next'] = example.groupby("A")['date'].shift(-1).reset_index()
s = example[['A',
    'B', 
    'C',
    'D']].ne(example[['A','B','C','D']].shift(1)).any(axis=1).cumsum()
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible sample of your DataFrame. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20159305/5901382

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not as straight forward. Using arrays would simplify. See logic and code below

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, 'A', 50, 30, 40, 78, 65, None),
     (1, 'B', 56, 30, 30, 25, 67, 75),
    (1, 'C', 56, 30, 30, 25, 67, 75)],
    ['Id', 'Type', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'])

df.show()

w =Window.partitionBy().orderBy('id')

(df.withColumn('ABCD', array('A','B','C','D'))#Combine the columns into an array
 .withColumn('ABCDShift',lead('ABCD').over(w))#Shiftrows
 .withColumn('cumsum', when(expr("forall(transform(ABCD, (c,i)-> c==ABCDShift[i]),c->c==true)")=='true',0).otherwise(1))#Check if array elements at each index agree totally. If all agree,o, otherwise 1o, if there
 .withColumn('cumsum',sum('cumsum').over(w.rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding,0)))#Cumsum
                           ).drop('ABCDShift','ABCD').show(truncate=False)


|Id |Type|A  |B  |C  |D  |E  |F   |cumsum|
+---+----+---+---+---+---+---+----+------+
|1  |A   |50 |30 |40 |78 |65 |null|1     |
|1  |B   |56 |30 |30 |25 |67 |75  |1     |
|1  |C   |56 |30 |30 |25 |67 |75  |2     |
+---+----+---+---+---+---+---+----+------+
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I am getting below error "Undefined function: 'forall'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'func' . I am using Pyspark 2.7 by the way.

Comment: Came into effect in 3.0+

Comment: Thanks a lot @wwnde. It worked.. I used your logic and it worked